# Looping through Array and only receive specific data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Trying to pull out data from an Array to the Logger. 
The code looks like this:

```
function createTable() { 

var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Create a three-dimensional array containing the cell contents.
 var cells = [
   ['Row 1, Cell 1', 'Row 1, Cell 2', 'Row 1, Cell 3'],
   ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2', 'Row 2, Cell 3'],
   ['Row 3, Cell 1', 'Row 3, Cell 2', 'Row 3, Cell 3']
 ];

 // Build a table from the array.
 body.appendTable(cells);

for(var i=0; i<cells.length;i++){
  var cl = cells[i];
  Logger.log(cl[0]);  
}
```

So `Logger.log(cl[0]);` loggs this:

```
[16-01-18 12:52:40:577 CET] Row 1, Cell 1
[16-01-18 12:52:40:578 CET] Row 2, Cell 1
[16-01-18 12:52:40:578 CET] Row 3, Cell 1
```

Logger.log([1]); loggs this:

```
[16-01-18 12:53:46:036 CET] Row 1, Cell 2
[16-01-18 12:53:46:037 CET] Row 2, Cell 2
[16-01-18 12:53:46:037 CET] Row 3, Cell 2
```

**Question:** How can i get a specific value, for example if i **only** want `'Row2, Cell 3'` to be logged?

Comment: What about `Logger.log(cells[1][2])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the loop if you want to print just one cell..

```
Logger.log(cells[1][2]);
```

Comment: Logger.log(cells[1][2]);  Worked fine :) Thanks Lucian !

Comment: But it spits it out three times, do you know why? Look at this printscreen: http://imgur.com/gGjcTSs

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
for(var i=0; i<cells.length;i++){
    var cl = cells[i];
    if(cl[1] == 'Row2, Cell 3')
        Logger.log(cl[1]);
}
```